# Wordpress type htaccess if is url have conditions use this rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, rules

I have this code;

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2indexsef.php [QSA,L]
```

I want to use alternative sef side outside of script but I don't know the start line..

If the url have "/announcements/***" or "/contact/***" or "/contact" or blabla use;

```html
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2other.php [QSA,L]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

#insert new rules here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "(^/announcements|/contact)" [NC]
RewriteRule gotothisfile.php

# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2indexsef.php [QSA,L]
```

A common used rule for RewriteCond is to check if it starts with something. You do this by putting ^ at the beginning. In your examples, /contact/ and /contact both start with the same letters, so you don't need to handle them separately.

The pipe character | is used to allow for different words to be matched.

Be sure to not put $ at the end of the rule, as this means "end of url"

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I tried but I got 500 error.

Comment: just checked some local examples, I think the match expression needs to be in double quotes https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: I tested again not work.  I checked document but I can't found multiple link rule

Comment: Have you just tried the 2 lines I added by themselves?